# "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" for private routes after logging in JWT NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

I am working on a backend for a Online mediconsult app and I came across this error in the JWT authentication. Since I am a newbie I dunno much about this topic. I have this 3 routes on my NodeJS /register, /login, /appointments. I was able to hit "/register" and "/login" perfectly fine. But when I copy the JWT token generated by "/login" route and paste it 'authorization' header it throws the problem.

```
node:internal/errors:484
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:644:11)        
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\krish\Desktop\mrcooper-task\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\krish\Desktop\mrcooper-task\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at module.exports.login (C:\Users\krish\Desktop\mrcooper-task\server\controllers\authController.js:62:7) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

Node.js v18.12.0
```

A strange thing is, when I restart the server again with the same auth token, it works!.
Wonder why would it hit the above error before restarting ?

## Code

### index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();

require('dotenv').config();

//External routes
const authRoutes = require("./routes/authRoutes");
const appointRoutes = require("./routes/appointRoutes");

// Middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//DB connection
const dbURI =
  process.env.DB_URL;
mongoose
  .connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then((result) =>
    app.listen(8080, () =>
      console.log("App sucessfully started on localhost port 8080")
    )
  )
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

//Internal routes
app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(appointRoutes);
```

### appointRoutes.js

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const verify = require("./verifyToken")

const router = Router();

router.get("/appointments",verify, (req, res) => {
  res.send({ message: "Appointment route" });
});

module.exports = router;
```

### authRoutes.js

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const { registerValidator, loginValidator } = require("../validation");

const router = Router();

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  //Validate data before creating a user
  const { error } = registerValidator(req.body);
  if (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  }
  //Check if email already exists
  const emailExists = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (emailExists) {
    return res.status(400).send("Email already exists");
  }

  const { name, email, password, catogery, DOB } = req.body;

  //Hash password
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
  //console.log(hashedPassword);
  try {
    const user = await User.create({
      name,
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
      catogery,
      DOB,
    });
    res.status(201).json({ user: user._id });
  } catch (err) {
    //console.log(err);
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
});

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  //Validate data before authenticating a user
  const { error } = loginValidator(req.body);
  if (error) {
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  }
  //Check if email dosen't exists
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (!user) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send("Email dosen't exists. Please register and try again");
  }
  //Passowrd is incorrect
  const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if (!validPassword) return res.status(400).send("Invalid Passowrd");

  //Create and assign JWT token
  const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET)
  res.header('auth-token', token).send(token);
  //console.log(email, password);
  res.send("Logged In!");
});

module.exports = router;
```

### Here's what I did

I did few googles and searches on this error and found out that this error mainly throws out when we return multiple response per cycle. I checked the code below and I did'nt see multiple response coming from neither /login route nor /appointments route. Would there be any response leaks from if conditions accidentaly?

When I exit from nodemon and start again with the same take generated, now it can hit the /appointment. I wonder how it works ?

Comment: Your error is at `at module.exports.login (C:\Users\krish\Desktop\mrcooper-task\server\controllers\authController.js:62:7) `. Please share that code as well.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I merged authRoutes and authController since Stackoverflow would'nt allow me to post long questions. Btw I identified the error ... I've given 2 res.send (last 2 lines before modules.exports in authROutes.js). THanks for the help btw

Comment: Okay. This error only comes when there is already a response sent, and again for the same `res` object, 2nd or more responses are being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get error when function like this

```
if(statement){
 res.send(something)
}

res.send(something)
```

because code is continue after res.send() function

You must fix it to

```
if(statement){
 return res.send(something)
}

return res.send(something)
```

and your res.send function in authController.js:62:7

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I merged authRoutes and authController since Stackoverflow has some certain limit in posting questions for new users.Btw, i've identified the error - I've given 2 res.send (last 2 lines before modules.exports in authROutes.js). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where is my useful point :D